# Размер картинки в paint и в pdf

Tags: pdf, png

не могу разобраться в ситуации. У меня есть картинка в png, Paint говорит что она 500x500 пикселей, что порядка 13 сантиметров. Почему когда я её добавляю в существующий или новый pdf файл её размер становится порядка 4 сантиметров?

Comment: Это вы с чего вообще взяли "порядка 13 сантиметров" ?)

Comment: В pdf скорее всего вставилось c 300 dpi (точек на дюйм), это более-менее стандартное разрешение печати. 500px / 300 dpi * 2.54 (cm/in) =  4.23 cm. Откуда 13 см взялось - не понятно.

Comment: А, понял, если "стандартное" экранное разрешение брать 96 dpi, то получается как раз 13.22 по той же формуле. Но pdf это формат для печати по сути, а не для экрана.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потому что пиксели и сантиметры это как рубли и доллары. Нельзя сказать сколько долларов в 1000 рублей, если неизвестен обменный курс.

Обменный курс между пикселями и сантиметрами при печати на бумагу называется [dpi](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dots_per_inch) - dots per inch (на самом деле даже не сантиметрами, а дюймами). Т.е. одно и то же изображение можно напечатать как на 10х10 см, так и на 2х2 метра, в зависимости от того, с какой плотностью напечатаны пиксели и какого они размера.

Если пойти в Paint в меню Файл - Свойства, то там будет написано 96 точек на дюйм. 500 / 96 = 5,2 дюйма, что и есть примерно 13 см. А стандарт вывода на печать (а формат pdf это именно для вывода на печать) - 300 dpi, что и дает примерно 4,1 см.